# Add marks from equation

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot with a bunch of *marks* on it. I want to automate the y-coordinate calculation of the *marks* (i.e. given the x-coordinates I want the marks to be added automatically using the equation).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 7cm, compat = newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [no marks] {x^2};
            % Need to automate the following y-coordinate calculations
            \addplot [only marks] coordinates {(-2, {(-2)^2}) (0, {0^2}) (3, {3^2})};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with using `samples at = {...}` key:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 7cm, compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [no marks] {x^2};
            \addplot [only marks, samples at={-2,0,3}] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hopelessly overlooked the `samples at` key! I'm pretty convinced that it's not worth it, but is it possible to achieve the same using a single `\addplot` call?

Comment: @Saptam, at least very hard. They have different number of samples and extracting them those, where you like to have marks is more complex (if even possible)  as write new `\addplot`.